# Performance of MarshalByRefObject Attribute in the same AppDomain

Tags: c#, marshalling, sandbox, appdomain

I need to add the MarshalByRefObject attribute to some classes (that define the interface of a plug-in) to allow sandboxing of these plug-ins. 
These classes are also used in a "non-plugin" context in a completely different application, but the attributes are in code. Do I will have any performance penalties in this other application without extra AppDomains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have no major performance impact, if it is being called from the same AppDomain none of the methods of `MarshalByRefObject` will be called.

If there was a major impact than WinForms would be in a lot of trouble considering [`Control`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx) derives from `MarshalByRefObject`